# How to reuse inputstream from java.net.socket?

Tags: java, sockets

I want to make http request with socket because I want to test how many sockets I can create my server. So I write and read from my server using `OutputStream` and `InputStream`. But I can't read from the input stream again after the first response. Do you know how to read the second response without closing the socket?
Here is my code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(address, 80), 1000);
socket.setSoTimeout(25*1000);

OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();        
os.write(getRequest(host)); // some request as bytearray, it has Connection: Keep-Alive in the header
os.flush();

InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

String response = IOUtils.toString(bis);
System.out.println("RESPONSE = \n" + response); // this works fine

os.write(getRequestBodyBa()); // send another request, i can see it sent to server with wireshark
os.flush();

// try to read again but it always return empty string            
response = IOUtils.toString(bis); // how to read the second response?????
System.out.println("RESPONSE = \n" + response);        

os.close();
is.close();
socket.close();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the HTTP standard are to close the connection after each response, unless the request has the [Connection header set to keep-alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection).

Comment: But the OP is using a socket, how do you know he's using HTTP over it?

Comment: Well, I guess if the "server" isn't a web server, then my answer does not apply.

Comment: I am sending http request with Connection: Keep-Alive in the header.

Comment: If the connection is closing, and you are not closing it on the client-side, then the server is doing it.  Perhaps you are asking the wrong question.  I think the right one is "Why is my server code closing the connection".  If you are sending to a web server, then the answer is most likely that either your web server doesn't support "keep-alive" or you are not setting it correctly.  If you are not sending to a web server, then you will have to look at the server code to determine what it's doing.  Keep-alive may not be supported/turned on for all web servers, so there is that too.

Comment: I don't think my server closing the connection. I can see the tcp socket still open in wireshark. It is just that I got empty string from reading the same inputstream. Am I supposed to read from the same inputstream or it should do something else?

Comment: This article might help:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html

Comment: Also, why are you using Socket and not HttpURLConnection. Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

`IOUtils.toString(InputStream)` reads the stream to EOS, so there can't be anything left to read for next time. Don't use it. You need to parse the response headers, work out whether there is a Content-Length header, if so read the body for exactly that many bytes; if there is no Content-Length header (and no chunking) the connection is closed after the body so you can't send a second command; etc etc etc. It is endless. Don't use a `Socket` for this either: use an HTTP `URL` and `URLConnection.`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try it and let you know. Do you know a way to control the number of underlying sockets that is buffered by HTTPURLConnnection or URLConnection? I want to control that to test my server.

Comment: If you call disconnect() after using each URLConnection there shouldn't be any connection pooling.

Comment: @CodeChimp Your comment belongs under the question, not here.